# Causing a buffer overflow, segfault

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to cause a buffer overflow in the following, very simple, program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void badf(int n, char c, char* buffer)
{

    char mycode[] = {
0xeb, 0x0f, 0xb8, 0x0b,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8b,
0x1c, 0x24, 0x8d, 0x0c,
0x24, 0x31, 0xd2, 0xcd,
0x80, 0xe8, 0xec, 0xff, 
0xff, 0xff, 0x2f, 0x62,
0x69, 0x6e, 0x2f, 0x6c, 
0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00
}; // 37 bytes

// Overwrite Base Pointer
    //mycode[37] = 0x29;
//mycode[38] = 0xf4;
//mycode[39] = 0xff;
//mycode[40] = 0xbf;

    // Overwrite Instruction Pointer
    // Using debugger, found mycode[] to be loaded in: 0xbffff42d
    mycode[41] = 0x2d;
    mycode[42] = 0xf4;
    mycode[43] = 0xff;
    mycode[44] = 0xbf;

}

void f(int n, char c)
{
    char buffer[37];    
    badf(n,c,buffer);
}

void test()
{
    printf("test");
}

int main()
{
    f(37,0x00);
    return 0;
}
```

(I've successfully managed to execute `test()` from the buffer overflow before) Now I'm trying to execute mycode[] by overwriting the instruction pointer with the start of mycode in the stack.

This only half works, the program jumps to the right address, where I can see the correct machine code in the debugger, but then crashes with a segmentation fault, instead of executing the following instructions (see screenshot).

[image]

**I'm trying to figure out why he crashes before executing the contents of the "injected" code.** I'm relatively new to this sort of stuff, I understand segmentation fault means I'm attempting to access memory the OS doesn't want me to?

(PS: 32bit Linux machine, compiling with `-fno-stack-protector` so I can play with this stuff)

(If any more info is needed I will gladly update the post)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

This sort of exciting trick doesn't work nowadays anymore, sadly. Blame the virus people.

Data segments are marked with the [NX (no execute)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) bit -- which is what triggers the segfault. CPU sees PC in a no-execute region.

Why don't you try overwriting the code of a "real" function pointer (take the address of an existing function) and see what happens (this will possibly fail because self-modifying code is also frowned upon by the compiler / linker / OS, also due to above-mentioned virus people)

Comment: Ok thank you. This is actually for an exercise for school but I'm doing it at home. Do you think I can conclude that I've successfully injected the code and redirected the instruction pointer, but that my modern Debian distro is preventing this for happening?

Comment: You can only conclude that you've successfully injected some machine code into a variable, then failed to execute it. Perhaps it would have worked were it not for the NX protections, perhaps not. Update: see suggestion in edited answer

Answer (score 3):

If it's Linux, you can probably make it work by downloading and installing execstack, and follow the instructions [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack). The segmentation fault is probably a result from your elf binaries by default setting the nx bit, which exectstack selectively undoes. If this doesn't work, you might trigger additional protections, which you may or may not be able to disable.

Comment: I tried compiling with: "gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -g -static -o bof bof.c" which should do the same no?

Comment: @Juicy: this wouldn't work on my distro. Execstack needed to be separately downloaded and installed, and you use it execstack -s <binary name>. You occasionally see the syntax you write suggested, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's in the repositories though (for my distro); so simply doing sudo apt-get install execstack should take care of install and configuration.

Comment: Thank you! Gave that a try but it's still giving me the seg fault. I believe, as I told dan3, that I've actually done what my lecturer wanted, it's not working on my Debian but hopefully will work on our Uni's Ubuntus.

Comment: Well the code that shows up in the debugger at that address is exactly the machine code I tried to inject (system call to execv), so it seems like the right code at the right address

Comment: @Juicy: Yw! Are you positive that it jumps to the right address? If you confirm in gdb, that's no proof: gdb creates its own address space that nowadays usually differs from that of your machine. Type su, then echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space (==disable ASLR). Them try again. Note that you cannot sudo this statement; need to be su first before echo'ing. I'd also carefully check your code for syntax errors. Most old exploits still run fine (eg, shell code insertion after buffer overflow, as you seem to do) after doing all of the above (including disabling canaries, as you do)

Comment: @Juicy: what you see in gdb is before ASLR scrambles your system's address space. You cannot rely on it, which is extremely inconvenient when you play with overflows; but I know no way around it.